# TApplication.MainFormOnTaskbar version requirements

Tags: delphi, compatibility, vcl

When this property has been introduced?

(if it says answer is too short - include VERnnn conditional symbol :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "non-breaking" release of RAD Studio 2007 introduced TApplication.MainFormOnTaskbar (and broke Delphi 2006).

Comment: second that. Unfortunately, commercial software vendors only count forward compatibility problems as **breaking**; and do not care much about *backward compatibility* (`NO COMPLAINING ! GO BUY A NEW VERSION!`), which is important to open source developers.

Comment: @GolezTrol, really simple - create a new project in D207 or higher, and try to build it in (say) D7. Proper patch is trivial but requires version # of symbol introduction, and here we are - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167554/tapplication-mainformontaskbar-version-requirements)

Comment: I meant that Delphi 2007's RTL and VCL was named rtl100.bpl/vcl100.bpl what is also the name of Delphi 2006's RTL/VCL. And that broke the Delphi 2006 IDE and all D2006 application that are compiled against packages.

Answer (score 5):

This property was introduced in Delphi 2007. One of several sources is [About.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/hide_taskbutton.htm):

> With Delphi 2007, a new property of
>   the Application object, the
>   `MainFormOnTaskbar` property controls
>   how Windows taskbar buttons are
>   handled by VCL.

Comment: No vote/accept for you!.. Despite being first to supply a correct answer, you haven't told about what it breaks.. :o

Comment: @Sertac: The question wasn't about what it breaks.

Comment: @Andreas - That's why I put the `:0` to the end of the answer. But I guess I shouldn't really get involved, this is not the first time I misunderstand sth.. :)

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz, O_o looking at exact answer timestamps reveals what this one was first! Yes, i was distracted by *breaking* filler :) Next time, then!

Answer (score 4):

Delphi 2007. And yeah, that answer exeeds 30 characters. ;)